# Distribution law among direct product, wedge sum and smash product

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

By distribution law I mean the following

$$\text{write} \,\, A \times (B \vee C) \,\,\text{in terms of} \,\, A \times B, A \times C$$

$$\text{write} \,\, A \times (B \wedge C) \,\,\text{in terms of} \,\, A \times B, A \times C$$

$$\text{write} \,\, A \vee (B \times C) \,\,\text{in terms of} \,\, A \vee B, A \vee C$$

$$\text{write} \,\, A \vee (B \wedge C) \,\,\text{in terms of} \,\, A \vee B, A \vee C$$

$$\text{write} \,\, A \wedge (B \times C) \,\,\text{in terms of} \,\, A \wedge B, A \wedge C$$

$$\text{write} \,\, A \wedge (B \vee C) \,\,\text{in terms of} \,\, A \wedge B, A \wedge C$$

The anwsers may have scattered here and there but I would like to consolidate them into one single post so that people may save as reference.  In addition it would be great that proof or reference is attached and comparison is made.  If there is no general formula then special cases are also welcome.